# Bouncy Castle AES-GCM mode vs OpenSSL AES-GCM?

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, aes, bouncycastle

I am trying to do some research on AES-GCM. I am trying to encrypt some data using Bouncy Castle's AES-GCM algorithm implementation and then decrypt it using openSSL's AES-GCM, but I couldn't.
I checked in Bouncy Castle, it returns a single output (ciphertext having length equal to the length of the input plus authentication tag), but in openSSL there are 2 outputs... 1 is the cipher text equal to the length of the input, and the other output is the tag length.

I checked that both follow the same standard, NIST 800-38D. I checked several of the posts but nowhere was mentioned how to do it. But also nowhere is it mentioned that we can't. Any idea?

Comment: Didn't notice this question as the Java and encryption tags were both missing after migration.

Answer (score 5):

You've simply got to concatenate the ciphertext and tag to decrypt with Bouncy or split the ciphertext and tag to verify using OpenSSL. The tag length should be an **pre-configured** input for the GCM mode, so it should always be possible to distinguish between ciphertext and authentication tag.